# text-indent in SELECT elements no longer working in Chrome

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

http://jsfiddle.net/PFBqq/

On Windows XP, it's working fine in Firefox 3.6 and Safari 4, but it doesn't seem to be working in the latest version (13) of Chrome. Unless I'm mistaken, I remember it *used to* work?

Anyone have a hack/fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `select` and `option` elements are hardly stylable and have a lot of issues in different browsers.

So, if you really want the indentation the only way to do it without writing custom select is adding `&nbsp;`s to the start of the lines [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/PFBqq/1/).

However, there are downsides of this hack: with the spaces at the start of options you couldn't jump to the desired options from the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

It will work if you specify **line-height**

```
select{
height:34px; //optional
line-height: 34px;
text-indent: 20px;
```

}

Please look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFBqq/35/)

Hope it solves your issue